# Load and display data with condition, but the condition is not met

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

Even i specify the mapping and the size.[image]

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([0, width])
          .padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([height, 0]);

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.sales = +d.sales;
  });
```

here i specify the domain of data

```
  // Scale the range of the data in the domains
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {if(d.sales>40){return d.salesperson;}}));
  y.domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.sales; })]);

  // append the rectangles for the bar chart
  let finalData=svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data.filter(function(d){if(d.sales>40) {return d;}}));
      finalData.enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.salesperson); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.sales); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.sales); });
```

here i add axis

```
  // add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

});
```

Here is the csv file

```
salesperson,sales
Bob,43
Robin,12
Anne,41
Mark,16
Joe,59
Eve,38
Karen,21
Kirsty,25
Chris,30
Lisa,47
Tom,5
Stacy,20
Charles,50
Mounir,56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That result is expected: you have `undefined` values in the scale's domain.

The issue is that `Array.prototype.map` cannot skip elements. For instance:

```js
const arr = [70, 20, 50, 80, 10, 90, 40];
console.log(arr.map(d => {
  if (d > 40) return d;
}))
```

As you can see this does not filter the array removing elements whose value is less than 40: the array's length keeps the same, but now it has several `undefined`.

Therefore, the solution is filtering the `data`, just like you did in the `data()` method:

```
data = data.filter(function(d){if(d.sales>40) {return d;}})
```

And use that filtered array for the scale's domain.

By the way, you can simplify the filter to just this:

```
data = data.filter(function(d){return d.sales>40})
```